# Android sdk not getting installed

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am having trouble in installing Android studio to Mac machine. While installing a pop up like in the image comes.[First Image:No SDK Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK1um.png) . Here they mentioned "before continuing, you must download the necessary components or select an existing SDK".

If I click next I am getting this screen [Android SDK Location, but even that path is not created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whSOM.png) . This image shows SDK path and an option to select SDK(but not able to select this check box)

Here I am not able to select the check box, also it is showing as installed. But there is no sdk installed at the location specified. So far I tried following.

1. Deleting all android set up and re-install.
2. Copying Android sdk from another machine to this location. In this case it list the copied SDKs in SDK manger, but no option to download (not listing the SDKs).

Any help(suggestions) is appreciated. I am stuck in this for last three days, kindly help.